# Insert row into MySQL database with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can someone spot the mistake:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO comments (event_id, fulltext, date_posted) VALUES (5, 'Hallo', 430234)");
```

The connection is established, but it just doesn't insert a new row.

```
include("../../connect.php");

$event_id = intval($_GET["event_id"]);
$fulltext = $_GET["fulltext"];
$date = intval($_GET["date"]);

mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO comments ('event_id', 'fulltext', 'date_posted') VALUES (5, 'Hallo', 430234)");

echo "INSERT INTO comments (event_id, fulltext, date_posted) VALUES (5, 'Hallo', 430234)";

mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: please share complete code, and what are you getting in return on `mysqli_query`? Probably you haven't selected database?

Comment: ok added more code, and as i said the connection is established and the correct database is selected

Comment: add some debugging!  **if (!mysqli_query($link, "'")) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    }** or something like that, there are plenty of ways to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FULLTEXT** is reserved word in **mysql** you can't use it as column name use below query with `` ` `` around column name

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO comments 
(`event_id`, `fulltext`, `date_posted`) VALUES (5, 'Hallo', 430234)");
```

Comment: What error it is showing? Try the same query in `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''event_id', 'fulltext', 'date_posted') VALUES (5, 'Hallo', 430234)' at line 1

Comment: You have to use `(backtick) not '(single quote) around column name.

Comment: @user1734282 Have you understood it properly and checked?

Comment: yes i cant use the variable full text because its a reserved word in mysql. so i have to put it between backticks.